# Calculating significance of PRE (proportional reduction in error)

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to calculate the significance of the PRE for two linear models. All of my variables are continuous (so I cant use the DAMisc package). I tried to do it by hand using the following R code, but I keep getting NaN when I test it. What did I do wrong?

```
library(psych)
modelC<-lm(reason.4~reason.16,data=iqitems)
modelA<-lm(reason.4~reason.16+reason.17,data=iqitems)

SSEC<-sum(modelC$residuals^2) #2019
SSEA<-sum(modelA$residuals^2) #1977
PRE=(SSEC-SSEA)/SSEC #0.02
pA<-2
pC<-1
n<-min(summary(modelA)$df)+1 #4
deg_freedom<-min(summary(modelA)$df) #3
Fvalue <- (PRE/(pA-pC))/((1-PRE)*(n-pA)) #0.0105
pf(Fvalue,pC-pA,deg_freedom,lower.tail=FALSE) #NaN
```

Comment: Have you checked for missing values in the residuals vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of the `pf` function is the degrees of freedom of the numerator of the f-statistic and the third argument is the degrees of freedom of the denominator of the f-statistic.

The degrees of freedom of your second argument is `-1` as is right now as `pC - pA = 1 - 2 = -1`. This is what gives you the error as the degrees of freedom are non-negative.I have no experience in PRE I think you need:

```
#second argument being pA - pC = 1
> pf(0.0105, 1, 3,lower.tail=FALSE)
[1] 0.9248493
```